# Draw properly sized rectangle around text

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to draw a popup tooltip on hover when the user mouses over a pie chart. The following works, but the problem is the rectangle is a fixed size. How might one go about making the rectangle fit the size of the actual text?

```
    // Draw rectangle
    popup
        .append("rect")
        .attr("x", x + 5)
        .attr("y", y - 5)
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .attr("rx", 5)
        .attr("ry", 5)
        .style("fill", popupFillColor)
        .style("stroke", stroke)
        .style("stroke-width", 2);

    // add text
    popup
        .append("text")
        .attr("x", x + 10)
        .attr("y", y + 10)
        .text(e.seriesValue[0] + `: ${e.pValue} (${percent})`)
        .style("font-family", "sans-serif")
        .style("font-size", 14)
        .style("fill", stroke);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **getBBox**:

```js
const x = 50, y = 30;

const svg = d3.select('svg');

const rect = d3.select('svg')
  .append('rect')
  .style('fill', 'none')
  .style('stroke', 'black');
  
const text = svg.append('text')
  .text('This is my text')
  .attr('x', x)
  .attr('y', y)
  
const box = text.node().getBBox();
console.log(box)

const X_MARGIN = 20;
const Y_MARGIN = 10;
rect
  .attr('x', box.x - X_MARGIN)
  .attr('y', box.y - Y_MARGIN)
  .attr('width', box.width + X_MARGIN * 2)
  .attr('height', box.height + Y_MARGIN * 2)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Comment: Sweeeeeeeeeeeeeet! Thanks so much!!