# how to put dynamic data text inside rectangle in d3

Tags: d3.js

Update method : Thanks in advance. I am creating rectangles based on the api response data. The rectangles will will be removed and re-created when the new data come back from api. I want to achieve same thing  for adding text inside the rectangles, means as soon as I receive the fresh data text should be overrided or re-created based on the data.

```
          /* update selection*/
      var rectangles = vis.ganttSvgRef.selectAll("rect").data(chartData);
         /*exit selection*/
       rectangles.exit().remove();
        /*enter selection*/
      var innerRects = rectangles.enter().append("rect").merge(rectangles)
    .attr("x", function (d) {
        return vis.timeScale(parseTime(d.arrivalTime_data)) + sidePadding;
    })
    .attr("y", function (d, i) {
        for (var j = 0; j < slotNumber.length; j++) {
            if (d.slot == slotNumber[j]) {
                return vis.yScale(d.slot);
            }
        }
    })
    .attr("width", function (d) {
        return (vis.timeScale(parseTime(d.departureTime_data)) - 
      vis.timeScale(parseTime(d.arrivalTime_data)));
    })
    .attr("height", barHeight)
    .attr("stroke", "none")
    .attr("fill", function (d) {
        for (var i = 0; i < vesselsNames.length; i++) {
            return serviceColorSelector[d.serviceName_data]
        }
    })
```

how to add the text in the rectangles in middle, which should also get update based on the data receive. Thanks

**Updated code as suggested by @Michael Rovinsky** : This code works perfectly fine for appending the text inside the rect, but on few rect the text is overflowing outside the rect area. I don't want to show the text if it overflow from rect area or how can i hide the text if it overflow from rect area ?

```
 var rectangles = vis.ganttSvgRef.selectAll("rect")
        .data(chartData);
    rectangles.exit().remove();

    var innerRects = rectangles.enter().append("g");
    let rectinst = innerRects.append("rect").merge(rectangles)
        .attr("x", function (d) {
            return vis.timeScale(parseTime(d.arrivalTime_data)) + 
                   sidePadding;
        })
        .attr("y", function (d, i) {
            for (var j = 0; j < slotNumber.length; j++) {
                if (d.slot == slotNumber[j]) {
                    return vis.yScale(d.slot);
                }
            }
        })
        .attr("width", function (d) {
            return (vis.timeScale(parseTime(d.departureTime_data)) - 
        vis.timeScale(parseTime(d.arrivalTime_data)));
        })
        .attr("height", barHeight)
        .attr("stroke", "none")
        .attr("fill", function (d) {
            for (var i = 0; i < vesselsNames.length; i++) {
                return serviceColorSelector[d.serviceName_data]
            }
        })
    let text = vis.ganttSvgRef.selectAll(".rect-text")
        .data(chartData);
    text.exit().remove();
    innerRects.append("text").merge(text)
        .attr("class", 'rect-text')
        .text(function (d) {
            let rectWidth = (vis.timeScale(parseTime(d.departureTime_data)) - 
          vis.timeScale(parseTime(d.arrivalTime_data)));
            console.log("rect width : ", rectWidth)
            console.log("d.vesselName_data : ", 
        vis.timeScale(d.vesselName_data.length))
            return d.vesselName_data;
        })
        .attr("x", function (d) {
            return (vis.timeScale(parseTime(d.departureTime_data)) -  
         vis.timeScale(parseTime(d.arrivalTime_data))) / 2 + 
         vis.timeScale(parseTime(d.arrivalTime_data)) + sidePadding;
           })
        .attr("y", function (d, i) {
            for (var j = 0; j < slotNumber.length; j++) {
                if (d.slot == slotNumber[j]) {
                    return vis.yScale(d.slot) + (barHeight / 2);
                }
            }
        })
        .attr("font-size", barHeight / 2)
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("text-height", barHeight)
        .attr("fill", '#fff');
```

Answer (score 1):

Append "**g**" instead of "**rect**" on **enter**():

```
const containers = rectangles.enter().append("g");
```

Append "**rect**" and "**text**" under "**g**":

```
containers.append("rect").attr('width', ...).attr('height', ...)...

containers.append("text").text('My Text Here')...
```

Comment: You ROCKS Michael. It solve my problem. Thank you very very much. One more thing, I am running into one more issue now, that is for few rect which are smaller in size , the text content overflow out from rectangle box. Can you suggest me how can I fix that. I have pasted the code above.

Comment: You can find an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67042128/draw-properly-sized-rectangle-around-text/67042648

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own text wrapping function d3 based on the rect dimensions and given padding.
Please check following link for customised text wrapping and overflow control in d3.js-

**Code-** [text-wrapping-in-d3](https://codepen.io/deekshagupta/pen/dyNwoQj)

```
    function wrap(text) {
    text.each(function() {
        var text = d3.select(this);
        var words = text.text().split(/\s+/).reverse();
        var lineHeight = 20;
        var width = parseFloat(text.attr('width'));
        var y = parseFloat(text.attr('y'));
        var x = text.attr('x');
        var anchor = text.attr('text-anchor');
    
        var tspan = text.text(null).append('tspan').attr('x', x).attr('y', y).attr('text-anchor', anchor);
        var lineNumber = 0;
        var line = [];
        var word = words.pop();

        while (word) {
            line.push(word);
            tspan.text(line.join(' '));
            if (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() > width) {
                lineNumber += 1;
                line.pop();
                tspan.text(line.join(' '));
                line = [word];
                tspan = text.append('tspan').attr('x', x).attr('y', y + lineNumber * lineHeight).attr('anchor', anchor).text(word);
            }
            word = words.pop();
        }
    });
}

function dotme(text) {
    text.each(function() {
        var text = d3.select(this);
        var words = text.text().split(/\s+/);
        
        var ellipsis = text.text('').append('tspan').attr('class', 'elip').text('...');
        var width = parseFloat(text.attr('width')) - ellipsis.node().getComputedTextLength();
        var numWords = words.length;
        
        var tspan = text.insert('tspan', ':first-child').text(words.join(' '));
        
        // Try the whole line
        // While it's too long, and we have words left, keep removing words
        
        while (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() > width && words.length) {
            words.pop();
            tspan.text(words.join(' '));
        }
        
        if (words.length === numWords) {
            ellipsis.remove();
        }
    });
}

d3.selectAll('.wrapme').call(wrap);
d3.selectAll('.dotme').call(dotme);
```